# How to Send Ajax Parameters through angular server route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, meanjs

I am using MeanJs Stack

I need to call the following Api :

```
http://localhost/api/movies/movieId/Action?page=1&perPage=10
```

How to send params `(page='+:id+page='+pageNum+'&perPage='+perPage)` in Server Route

I am sending the Following way which is not Helping

**movies.server.routes.js**

```
app.route('/api/movies/:id/Action?page='+:id+'page'=+pageNum+'&perPage'=+perPage')//But it is not recognising by rout and parameters are not sending 
            .get(movies.readAllMovies);//triggers and call the api .
```

Could you guys give me some Hint of it ?
Sorry for the horizontal scroll guys :-) .

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you have written in your params, but it looks to me like you would just do:
`('/api/movies/'+id+'/Action?page='+pageNum+'&perPage='+perPage)`

Comment: That is my bad sorry just updated post with that .. i did same way not working .. that is the exact issue it is sending only api but not the ajax params

Comment: I recommend using `'/api/movies/:id/Action'` for the route and just grabbing the query strings using the request.query (in your get method).
ex:`app.route('/api/movies/:id/Action')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    pageNum = req.query.page;
  })`
EDIT: apparently the Express documentation agrees -- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD

Comment: Actually i did experimented all these combinations before posting . the api staying pending status for long time and failing . unfortunately not working –

Answer (score 1):

According to ExpressJS [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), *query strings* are not part of a route definition.

Therefore, your route could be *refined* (apart from having a couple of syntax errors) as such:

```
app.route('/api/movies/:id/Action')
        .get(movies.readAllMovies);
```

Then, in the handler `movies.readAllMovies`, you can access query strings with `req.query`. That is, the `page` query string can be retried as `req.query.page` and so on.

**Note** that since expressJS uses regular expressions to match routes, a `?` will serve as a *quantifier* in regular expression terms.

Comment: Actually i did experimented all these combinations before posting  . the api staying pending status for long time and failing . unfortunately not working

Comment: Can you post the content of the `movies.readAllMovies` handler. I think you're not _sending_ any response from the handler. 
Also check the server console for any errors when the request is sent.

Comment: @  Ahmad Baktash Hayeri That method is good iam using req.query.page etc .. iam trying to figure out .. thanks for the valid info ? operator not works .. idk about that ..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in my opinion, you should be handling this through a service to return the result, and a RESTful endpoint on the node server to perform the query. I feel your above approach could use a serious re-visit conceptually, so here's how I'd tackle it.

1. You need to create a service or a factory for handling the requests to the api endpoint
2. Check out the below instructions for modifying your api endpoint so that it just pipes the response back to the service
3. Include the service in your angular module and consume it on demand in your controller / whatever

You should use request module and params, it is by far the easiest method of retrieving query params in get requests in my opinion and streaming the response is to just pipe the result of the url. This is super simple using request https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

**First, lets modify your endpoint and include the request module**

First `npm install request --save`

Then in your app include request `var request = require('request');`

**req.query.--name of queryparam**

and

**req.params.--name of param**

Then your endpoint is as simple as

```
app.get('/api/movies/:movieID/:Category', function(req, res){
var url='http://localhost/api/movies/' + req.params.movieID + '/' + req.params.Category +'?page=' + req.query.page + '&perPage=' + + req.query.page;
request(url).pipe(res);
```

});

**You should be able to hit this endpoint directly with a get request and it should work

**Then Create a Service to consume the result and provide it to the controller**